# No buttons on top panel appearing

Tags: panel, button

I've noticed that since 16.04 update some of programs has lost their buttons on the top panel. Some examples:

- Gnu Image Manipulation Program(GIMP)
- XChat-GNOME

It would be great to find out reason aswell as solution to this.

Comment: Do you mean menu?

Comment: I dont know how exactly it's called. It's the top menu row. By the way - it works well in browser, although here I really don't need it:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226) in 16.04 which has no ultimate fix till now. But this command can solve the problem temporarily:

```
initctl restart unity-panel-service
```

Comment: By the way - is this planned to be fixed?

Comment: it should be fixed in the following update

Comment: That sounds great!:)

Comment: Just a note - it's not yet fixed:D

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 will be released on July 21st! I hope this problem be solved before that. But I think it is better to assume it won't be solved before that date

Comment: Ah... OK! I will be waiting than.

Answer (score -1):

Have you used tweak-tool to change your theme?  Try resetting to a default theme.  I noticed the same issue, along with the fact that some windows (like gedit) couldn't be resized.  As soon as I changed my GTK+ theme back to Adwaita (default) everything worked right.  Do note, I run Gnome 3, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I used Unity Tweak Tool or something like that once. But all it did was a little change in color scheme and making top panel transparent. It hasn't done anything bad for ages...